# Django v1.10: Getting a JSON of all `Country` models stored in the model `Continent`

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I have the following models:

```
from django.db import models

MNL = 50
MCL = 5


class Continent(models.Model):


    """
    Fields
    """
    name = models.CharField("name", max_length=MNL, unique=True)
    code = models.CharField("code", max_length=MCL, default="", unique=True)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']

    """
    Methods
    """
    def __str__(self):
        return "%s, %s" % (self.name, self.code)


class Country(models.Model):

    """
    Fields
    """
    name = models.CharField("name", max_length=MNL, unique=True)
    capital = models.CharField("capital", max_length=MNL)
    code = models.CharField("code", max_length=MCL, default="", unique=True)
    population = models.PositiveIntegerField("population")
    area = models.PositiveIntegerField("area")
    continent = models.ForeignKey(Continent, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="countries")
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']


    """
    Methods
    """
    def __str__(self):
        return "%s, %s" % (self.name, self.code)
```

I need to be able to retrieve 2 things in JSON(P):

1. individual `Country`'s `capital`, `population` and `area` fields in the form `{"area":<area>,"population":<population>,"capital":<capital_name>}` and
2. in the case of a `Continent`, all of the countries in that continent in the form `{"code1":"name1", "code2":"name2",...}`

I've tried implementing the following views to achieve this:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404, JsonResponse
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict
import json

from .models import Continent, Country


def continent_json(request, continent_code):
    """ Write your answer in 7.2 here. """
    try:
        print("CONTINENT QuerySet: ", Continent.objects.filter(
            code__exact=continent_code).values("countries"))
        continent_data = json.dumps( list(Continent.objects.filter(
            code__exact=continent_code).values("countries") ) )
        print("CONTINENT JSON: ",continent_data)
    except Continent.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Requested continent does not exist.")

    # If JSONP
    if "callback" in request.GET:
        continent_data = "{}({})".format(
            request.GET["callback"],
            continent_data
            )
        return HttpResponse(continent_data)

    # Normal JSON
    return HttpResponse(continent_data, content_type="application/json")


def country_json(request, continent_code, country_code):
    """ Write your answer in 7.2 here. """
    try:
        #print("COUNTRY_OBJECT: "Country.objects.filter(code__exact=country_code).values())
        print("MODEL_LIST: ",list(Country.objects.filter(code__exact=country_code).values("capital","population","area")))
        country_data = json.dumps( list(Country.objects.filter(
            code__exact=country_code).values("code","name") ) )
        print("COUNTRY DATA: ", country_data)

    except Country.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Requested country does not exist.")

    # If JSONP
    if "callback" in request.GET:
        country_data = "{}({})".format(
            request.GET["callback"],
            country_data
            )
        return HttpResponse(country_data)

    # Normal JSON
    return HttpResponse(country_data, content_type="application/json")
```

However, this is not producing the results I want: the data is not actually coming back as JSON(P), but as either a dict or a list. This is a lot of code to shift through, but I'm at my wits end here.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If data is not wrapped in JSONP callback then clearly you are not entering `if "callback" in request.GET:` condition. Have you verified that `callback` parameter is present in `request.GET`?

Comment: It might or might not be. The code needs to work in both cases. If it is, the data should be returnen in a callback function. In my head this is what currently happens. The issue is that I can't seem to convert the models into JSON.

Comment: Yes but JSONP should be returned *only* if `callback` is present in `GET`.  S you saying that the despite `callback` being present in `GET` you still do not receive JSONP?

Comment: Nope, I get a list that contains a dictionary inside the callback function: `myCallbackFunction:([{"countries": null}])`, but I need a JSON object, don't I? In the case a a single country, I get an empty list: `[]`.

Comment: And you want to have what? This? `myCallbackFunction:({"countries": null})`

Comment: To my understanding, that is what I need for it to work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181845/discussion-between-kamil-niski-and-thesodesa).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you explained on chat:

You need to change your views to something like this

```
country_data = json.dumps(dict(Country.objects.filter(
        code__exact=country_code).values("code","name")[0])))
```

and for continent view:

```
continent = Continent.objects.get(code__exact=continent_code)
country_data = json.dumps(dict(continent.countries.values_list('code', 'name')))
```